# How can I kill Aegapodium for good?

Tags: weed-control

We're slowly losing our fight against Aegopodium (snow on the mountains). The specific name is [*Aegopodium podagraria*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aegopodium_podagraria), though we think of it as *Aegopodium obnoxiosio*. Tilling the bejabbers out of it only breaks up the roots and leads to a vigorous regrowth. Burning it out only wastes propane. In desperation, we tried herbicides on a test patch, but it seems to treat Roundup as fertilizer. Covering it with a plastic barrier doesn't seem to work, at least for two years of coverage. We don't have access to nuclear weapons, so that's out (and probably wouldn't work anyway). I suppose we could overplant it with kudzu, but that just trades one problem for another.

Sorry for the rant, but does anyone have a suggestion we've missed? I can't believe people actually recommend it as a groundcover.